# pd.melt() a dictionary/series of dataframes

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

For example I have the following map:

```
  {'df1': Jan    Feb    Mar
           1      3      5
           2      4      6
   'df2': Jan    Feb    Mar
           7      9      11
           8      10     12
    ......}
```

And I want the following output:

```
Jan  1
Jan  2
Feb  3
Feb  4
Mar  5
Mar  6
Jan  7
Jan  8
Feb  9
Feb  10
Mar  11
Mar  12
```

Does anyone knows if its possible to do it this way?
What I have tried is to iterate through DataFrames to try getting

```
  {'df1': Jan  1
          Jan  2
          Feb  3
          Feb  4
          Mar  5
          Mar  6

   'df2': Jan  7
          Jan  8
          Feb  9
          Feb  10
          Mar  11
          Mar  12
```

by using

```
for x in dfMap:
    df = pd.melt(list(x.values()))
```

Then try to concat it with df1m =

```
pd.concat(df.values(), ignore_index=True)
```

Which gave me error

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'columns'
```

I am fairly new to programming and really wanted to learn, will be nice if anyone can explain how this works, and why list or dict_values object has no attribute 'columns'.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can concat and stack:

```
out = pd.concat(d.values()).stack().droplevel(0)
```

Or:

```
out = pd.concat(d.values()).melt()
```

---

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(1,10).reshape(-1,3),columns=['Jan','Feb','Mar'])
d = {}
for e,i in df.iterrows():
    d[f"df{e+1}"] = i.to_frame().T
print(d,'\n')

out = pd.concat(d.values()).stack().droplevel(0)
print(out)
```

---

```
    {'df1':    Jan  Feb  Mar
0    1    2    3, 'df2':    Jan  Feb  Mar
1    4    5    6, 'df3':    Jan  Feb  Mar
2    7    8    9} 

Jan    1
Feb    2
Mar    3
Jan    4
Feb    5
Mar    6
Jan    7
Feb    8
Mar    9
dtype: int32
```

With `melt`:

```
out = pd.concat(d.values()).melt()
print(out)

  variable  value
0      Jan      1
1      Jan      4
2      Jan      7
3      Feb      2
4      Feb      5
5      Feb      8
6      Mar      3
7      Mar      6
8      Mar      9
```

EDIT, for edited question , try:

```
out = pd.concat(d).stack().sort_index(level=[0,-1]).droplevel([0,1])
```

---

Example below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(1,13).reshape(3,-1).T,columns=['Jan','Feb','Mar'])
d = {}
for e,i in df.groupby(df.index//2):
    d[f"df{e+1}"] = i
print(d,'\n')

out = pd.concat(d).stack().sort_index(level=[0,-1]).droplevel([0,1])
print(out)

{'df1':    Jan  Feb  Mar
0    1    5    9
1    2    6   10, 'df2':    Jan  Feb  Mar
2    3    7   11
3    4    8   12} 

Jan     1
Jan     2
Feb     5
Feb     6
Mar     9
Mar    10
Jan     3
Jan     4
Feb     7
Feb     8
Mar    11
Mar    12
dtype: int32
```

Or you can also convert the dataframe names as int and then sort:

```
out = (pd.concat(d.values(),keys=[int(key[2:]) for key in d.keys()])
   .stack().sort_index(level=[0,-1]).droplevel([0,1]))
```

Comment: Thanks, It worked but I do need to apologise to you that apparently I did some mistakes in my questions asking. I believe that its the matter of logic only right? The reason the output has to look like that is because it will be further changed into DateTime instead of months.

Comment: @user14783839 edited my answer, check EDIT section

Comment: I actually use the following code to get the dictionary,  (    dfMap = {}
for sheet_name in xls.sheet_names:
    dfMap[sheet_name] = xls.parse(sheet_name, header=4, usecols='C:N', skiprows= range(35,45), engine= 'openpyxl')       )     Which results in the key name in format "dict_keys(['1994_x0009__x0009_', '1995_x0009_', '1996_x0009_',..."     and error ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '', This is caused be the dict_keys format I supposed is that correct?

Comment: try `keys = [int(key.split("_")[0])  for key in dfMap.keys()]` inside `pd.concat`? @user14783839

Comment: @user14783839 if above doesnt work: you can create a separate question with all the necessary details so me or some other contributor can take a look and try to answer that question. This question in particular has been already answered since you provided the keys as `'df1'` and `'df2'`

Comment: yea sorry for the late update. It worked really well I really appreciate it ! I am actually curious why it becomes like "sheetname_x0009_", but nevertheless I can find it out myself. Thank you so much again, have a great day!